# Bootstrap : Show file name after select

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my form I have a file upload button. I want to show the file name that has been selected. However I cant seem to grab the name of the file and show it in my text box: [codepen here](http://codepen.io/isharief318/pen/beVLvG)

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-primary">
            Browse&hellip; <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').html($(this).val());">
        </span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="upload-file-info" readonly>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the **Val** for the input too ... change it:

> From .html() to .val()

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
    <label class="input-group-btn">
        <span class="btn btn-primary">
            Browse&hellip; <input id="my-file-selector" type="file" style="display:none;" onchange="$('#upload-file-info').val($(this).val());">
        </span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="upload-file-info" readonly>
</div>
```

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJeLeb)

Comment: perfect!! thanks. I had it working with out the text box earlier and suspected that the filename now generated was being covered by the input box, was this the case?

Comment: I don't think so you are just hiding the input file

Answer (score 1):

You can check the value of e.target.files[0].name

```
$('input:file').change(
    function(e){
        console.log(e.target.files[0].name);
    });
```

check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0gunajo/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple file upload input, you can use this to update file name on actual input

```js
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
  var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
  // change name of actual input that was uploaded
  $(e.target).next().html(fileName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for multiple:

```
 $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e) {
                            let fileNames = $.map(e.target.files, function(val) {
                                return val.name;
                            }).join(', ');
                            $(e.target).next().html(fileNames);
                        });
```