# Bootstrap 4 File Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am struggling with bootstrap 4 file browser. If I use custom-file-control I will see Choose file value all the time. 
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#file-browser

I would like to change the value of choose file after the file has been chosen. This value is actually hidden in css `.custom-file-control:lang(en)::after` and I do not know how to access and change it in javascript. I can get the value of chosen file like this:

```
document.getElementById("exampleInputFile").value.split("\\").pop();
```

not I need to change

```
.custom-file-control:lang(en)::after {
    content: "Choose file...";
}
```

somehow

link: http://codepen.io/Matoo125/pen/LWobNp

Comment: This question has been answered before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713126/bootstrap-show-file-name-after-select

Comment: not really, I asked how to change css property content, because that is where Bootstrap 4 has the text is renders in this approach. I do not see the value

Comment: but I want to access it dynamically based on the input value. How can I do that with css?

Comment: First, have you managed to change the placeholder/button value with CSS? The process of selecting the value has been answered in the other question

Comment: I can select the value with JS, but in bootstrap 4 this 'placeholder' value is in ::after { content : "..." } and I need to change that to see changes

Comment: Same question for [Bootstrap 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65770908/)

Comment: If using Bootstrap 5, try [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73138618/8706905) , some tricks are used but just works fine.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

***Updated 2021***

**Bootstrap 5**

Custom file input no longer exists so to change `Choose file...` you'd need to use JS or [some CSS like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65776036/171456).

**Bootstrap 4.4**

Displaying the selected filename can also be done with plain JavaScript. Here's an example that assumes the standard custom-file-input with label that is the next sibling element to the input...

```
document.querySelector('.custom-file-input').addEventListener('change',function(e){
  var fileName = document.getElementById("myInput").files[0].name;
  var nextSibling = e.target.nextElementSibling
  nextSibling.innerText = fileName
})
```

https://codeply.com/p/LtpNZllird

**Bootstrap 4.1+**

Now in Bootstrap 4.1 the "Choose file..." placeholder text is set in the **`custom-file-label`**:

```
<div class="custom-file" id="customFile" lang="es">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile" aria-describedby="fileHelp">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">
           Select file...
        </label>
</div>
```

Changing the "Browse" button text requires a little extra CSS or SASS. Also notice how [language translation works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#file-browser) using the `lang=""` attribute.

```
.custom-file-input ~ .custom-file-label::after {
    content: "Button Text";
}
```

https://codeply.com/go/gnVCj66Efp (CSS)
https://codeply.com/go/2Mo9OrokBQ (SASS)

**Another Bootstrap 4.1 Option**

Alternatively you can use this [custom file input plugin](https://github.com/Johann-S/bs-custom-file-input)

https://www.codeply.com/go/uGJOpHUd8L/file-input

---

**Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6** (Original Answer)

I think there are 2 separate issues here..

```
<label class="custom-file" id="customFile">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input">
        <span class="custom-file-control form-control-file"></span>
</label>
```

**1 - How the change the initial placeholder and button text**

In Bootstrap 4, the **initial** placeholder value is set on the `custom-file-control` with a CSS pseudo `::after` element based on the HTML language. The initial file button (which isn't really a button but looks like one) is set with a CSS pseudo `::before` element. These values can be overridden with CSS..

```
#customFile .custom-file-control:lang(en)::after {
  content: "Select file...";
}

#customFile .custom-file-control:lang(en)::before {
  content: "Click me";
}
```

**2 - How to get the selected filename value, and update the input to show the value.**

Once a file is selected, the value can be obtained using JavaScript/jQuery.

```
$('.custom-file-input').on('change',function(){
    var fileName = $(this).val();
})
```

However, since the placeholder text for the input is a pseudo element, [there's no easy way to manipulate this with Js/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/171456). You can however, have a another CSS class that **hides the pseudo content** once the file is selected...

```
.custom-file-control.selected:lang(en)::after {
  content: "" !important;
}
```

Use jQuery to toggle the `.selected` class on the `.custom-file-control` once the file is selected. This will hide the initial placeholder value. Then put the filename value in the `.form-control-file` span...

```
$('.custom-file-input').on('change',function(){
  var fileName = $(this).val();
  $(this).next('.form-control-file').addClass("selected").html(fileName);
})
```

You can then handle the file upload or re-selection as needed.

[Demo on Codeply (alpha 6)](http://www.codeply.com/go/SkIJQ5LqKp/custom-file-input)

Comment: `C:\fakepath\...` very funny.

Comment: 1) Or use `<html lang="en">`

Comment: Where is this `C:\fakepath\...` coming from?

Comment: @ZimSystem Thanks for the solution. I'm getting same C:\fakepath\.. in firefox developer edition, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Just did now, missed it the first time. Thanks.

Comment: you can also use:   .custom-file-control.selected::after {
  content: "" !important;
}  to make it work for all languages (if your site supports multiple languages)

Comment: I used this to get file name without "fakepath":
`var fileName = document.getElementById("upload-image-input").files[0].name;`

Comment: I assume it changed at some point, but now you are able to simply change the visible text snippet by setting the text of the `span` tag

Comment: Yes... the input placeholder, but not the button as explained above

Answer (score 81):

I just solved it this way

Html:

```
<div class="custom-file">
   <input id="logo" type="file" class="custom-file-input">
   <label for="logo" class="custom-file-label text-truncate">Choose file...</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.custom-file-input').on('change', function() { 
   let fileName = $(this).val().split('\\').pop(); 
   $(this).next('.custom-file-label').addClass("selected").html(fileName); 
});
```

**Note**: Thanks to [ajax333221](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250263/bootstrap-4-file-input/48942822?noredirect=1#comment89436997_48942822) for mentioning the `.text-truncate` class that will hide the overflow within label if the selected file name is too long.

Comment: Thanks for the `.split('\\').pop()` part!

Comment: @spaceemotion happy it helped

Comment: FWIW, I had to add `type="file"` to the `<input>` tag.  But otherwise, worked great.

Comment: @ghukill my answer was a quick design thingy, but i will just add the `type` attribute too, for those who will copy. Thanks

Comment: Worth saying you can hide the overflow with **text-truncate** like this `class='custom-file-label text-truncate'`

Comment: @ajax333221 that is awesome, didn't know about that class. Thanks. I just adjust ed answer.

Comment: @ajax333221 Using `text-truncate` I don't get ellipsis... If I don't use it, the text overruns the box (expected). But if I use `text-truncate` it just inserts text all the up to the end and stops (mid-letter depending on length). I even tried adding an inline style with `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, but no luck. Is this expected?

Answer (score 18):

As of **Bootstrap 4.3** you can change placeholder and button text inside the label tag:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile" data-browse="{Your button text}">{Your placeholder text}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to Bootstrap documentation?

Comment: @AbdelsalamShahlol - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#translating-or-customizing-the-strings-with-html

Answer (score 9):

**For changing the language of the file browser:**
As an alternate to what [ZimSystem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/zimsystem) mentioned (override the CSS), a more elegant solution is suggested by the bootstrap docs: build your custom bootstrap styles by adding languages in SCSS
Read about it here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#file-browser

*Note*: you need to have the lang attribute properly set in your document for this to work

**For updating the value on file selection:**
You could do it with inline js like this:

```
   <label class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" id="myfile" class="custom-file-input" onchange="$(this).next().after().text($(this).val().split('\\').slice(-1)[0])">
      <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
   </label>
```

*Note*: the `.split('\\').slice(-1)[0]` part removes the *C:\fakepath\* prefix

Comment: Nice.  Using this to add to all custom file inputs: `$('.custom-file-input').change(function () { $(this).next().after().text($(this).val().split('\\').slice(-1)[0]); });`

Answer (score 6):

**Bootstrap 4**

More details are [here](https://learncodeweb.com/snippets/browse-button-in-bootstrap-4-with-select-image-preview/) https://learncodeweb.com/snippets/browse-button-in-bootstrap-4-with-select-image-preview/

Today I need to create a browse button with a multi-upload files option all the above snippets are not good for me.

The [official Bootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#file-browser) is also not working when I select multiple files.

I come up with this code maybe will help others in the future.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="file"]').on("change", function() {
    let filenames = [];
    let files = document.getElementById("customFile").files;
    if (files.length > 1) {
      filenames.push("Total Files (" + files.length + ")");
    } else {
      for (let i in files) {
        if (files.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          filenames.push(files[i].name);
        }
      }
    }
    $(this)
      .next(".custom-file-label")
      .html(filenames.join(","));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container mt-5">
  <h1 class="text-center">Bootstrap 4 Upload multiple files</h1>
  <div class="col-sm-6 mr-auto ml-auto border p-4">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Upload Files</strong></label>
        <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple class="custom-file-input form-control" id="customFile">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="upload" value="upload" id="upload" class="btn btn-block btn-dark"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-upload"></i> Upload</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The working code example is given [here](https://learncodeweb.com/snippets/browse-button-in-bootstrap-4-with-select-image-preview/) with bootstrap 3 and bootstrap 4.3.1.

https://codepen.io/mianzaid/pen/GeEbYV

Comment: Actually, the most useful answer for me so +1. Minor improvement: add 'form-control' class to label element.

Answer (score 3):

For Bootstrap v.5

```
document.querySelectorAll('.form-file-input')
        .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', e => e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.form-file-text').innerText = e.target.files[0].name));
```

Affect all file input element. No need to specify elements id.

Answer (score 2):

In case, if you need a no jquery solution

```html
<label class="custom-file">
      <input type="file" id="myfile" class="custom-file-input" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.innerText = this.files[0].name">
      <span class="custom-file-control"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer with blue ***box-shadow,border,outline removed*** with file name fix in custom-file input of **bootstrap** appear on choose **filename** and if you not choose any file then show **No file chosen**.

```js
    $(document).on('change', 'input[type="file"]', function (event) { 
        var filename = $(this).val();
        if (filename == undefined || filename == ""){
        $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html('No file chosen');
        }
        else 
        { $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(event.target.files[0].name); }
    });
```

```css
    input[type=file]:focus,.custom-file-input:focus~.custom-file-label {
        outline:none!important;
        border-color: transparent;
        box-shadow: none!important;
    }
    .custom-file,
    .custom-file-label,
    .custom-file-input {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just add this in my CSS file and it works:

```
.custom-file-label::after{content: 'New Text Button' !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of jquery, it can be done like this.
Code:

```
$("input.custom-file-input").on("change",function(){if(this.files.length){var filename=this.file[0].name;if(filename.length>23){filename=filename.substr(0,11)+"..."+filename.substr(-10);}$(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").text(filename);}});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below given snippet to display the selected file name from the **file** input type.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]').forEach( input => {
    input.addEventListener('change', e => {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = input.files[0].name;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For "bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig":

```
document.querySelector('.custom-file-input').addEventListener('change',function(e){
   this.nextElementSibling.innerText = this.files[0].name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on @Elnoor answer, but working with multiple file upload form input and without the "fakepath hack":

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <input id="logo" type="file" class="custom-file-input" multiple>
    <label for="logo" class="custom-file-label text-truncate">Choose file...</label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function () {
    let filenames = [];
    let files = document.getElementById('health_claim_file_form_files').files;

    for (let i in files) {
        if (files.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            filenames.push(files[i].name);
        }
    }

    $(this).next('.custom-file-label').addClass("selected").html(filenames.join(',    '));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4.4:

Show a `choose file` bar. After a file is chosen show the file name along with its extension

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="idEditUploadVideo"
     onchange="$('#idFileName').html(this.files[0].name)">
    <label class="custom-file-label" id="idFileName" for="idEditUploadVideo">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use it globally on all custom inputs use following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.custom-file-input').on('change', function (e) {
         e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = e.target.files[0].name;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Bootstrap 5.2**
Custom file input without CSS.

**Image**
[image]

**Html Code**

```
<div class="input-group">   
     <input type="file" id="uploadFile_Plan_PDF" class="Zupload" accept="application/pdf" hidden/>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf"></i>
     </button>
     <input readonly="readonly" type="text" class="form-control">                                
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" disabled>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
     </button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-times"></i>
     </button>
</div>
```

**Js Code**

```
const collection_uploadFile = document.querySelectorAll(".Zupload");
for (let i = 0; i < collection_uploadFile.length; i++) {
  let uploadFile = collection_uploadFile[i]
  let buttonUpload = uploadFile.nextElementSibling;
  let textBoxUpload = buttonUpload.nextElementSibling;
  let buttonView = textBoxUpload.nextElementSibling;
  let buttonClear = buttonView.nextElementSibling;              

  uploadFile.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    textBoxUpload.value = this.value;
    buttonView.disabled = this.value?false:true;
  });
  buttonUpload.addEventListener('click', function (e) {uploadFile.click();});
  textBoxUpload.addEventListener('click', function (e) {uploadFile.click();});
  buttonClear.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    uploadFile.value =""; 
    uploadFile.dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
  });
}
```

**Demo**

[Zupload on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zemmouri/1ds90mex/12)

Answer (score -1):

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script>
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {var input = $(this), numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
  });
  $(document).ready( function() {
      $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {var input = $(this).parents('.custom-file').find('.custom-file-label'),
      log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;if( input.length ) {input.text(log);} else {if( log ) alert(log);}});
  });
});
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without JQuery

HTML:

```
<INPUT type="file" class="custom-file-input"  onchange="return onChangeFileInput(this);">
```

JS:

```
function onChangeFileInput(elem){
  var sibling = elem.nextSibling.nextSibling;
  sibling.innerHTML=elem.value;
  return true;
}
```

KliG