# bootstrap 4 file input doesn't show the file name

Tags: jquery, html, css, file-upload, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the custom-file-input class in Bootstrap 4.
after I chose which file I want to upload the filename do not show.

I use this code:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02">Choose file</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can fix it without getting too complicated?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You need to use javascript to show the name of the choosed file, as written in the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#file-browser

Here you can find the solution: [Bootstrap 4 File Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250263/bootstrap-4-file-input)

That's the code for your example:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02"/>
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile02">Choose file</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#inputGroupFile02').on('change',function(){
                //get the file name
                var fileName = $(this).val();
                //replace the "Choose a file" label
                $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I simply opt out of this and simply get the native file input?

Comment: this sets C:\fakepath\myfile.ext I'm on linux it is weird to see C:\... not really a good solution.

Comment: You can manipulate the string to remove "C\fakepath" to have only the filename.
    `var cleanFileName = fileName.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', " ");`

Comment: @adityaekawade I'd simplify this to say you can replace `var fileName = $(this).val();` with `var fileName = $(this).val().replace('C:\\fakepath\\', " ");` sound reasonable?

Comment: Why put an extra space? just do 
fileName.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', " ");

Comment: You better use `e.target.files[0].name` like Anuja below. That's just giving the name without the fake path...

Answer (score 97):

I have used following for the same:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
        var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
        $('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This got my 90% of the way. However I had multiple file inputs so needed to target by ID instead of class.

Comment: If you have several file inputs, you can use this: `$(e.target).siblings('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);` instead

Comment: You should use `.text(fileName)` instead of `.html(fileName)`.

Comment: This will be good if you have only 1 file input. Multiple file input will replace all the labels with the same file name (last file you choose).

Comment: If you have label next to input and everything in one div, you can do something like: `$(e.target).parent('div').find('label').html(fileName)`

Comment: I found a problem: after selecting a file, if you click again on "browse files" and select another or the same file, more than one file is sent to my backend! So how do you clear any previously selected files if you click on browse files again?

Comment: Another way to do it with multiple inputs:  
$(this).parent().find('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);

Answer (score 49):

The answer of Anuja Patil only works with a single file input on a page. This works if there are more than one. This snippet will also show all files if `multiple` is enabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.custom-file input').change(function (e) {
        var files = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $(this)[0].files.length; i++) {
            files.push($(this)[0].files[i].name);
        }
        $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(files.join(', '));
    });

</script>
```

Note that `$(this).next('.custom-file-label').html($(this)[0].files.join(', '));` does not work. So that is why the `for` loop is needed.

If you never work with mulitple files in the file upload, this simpler snippet can be used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.custom-file input').change(function (e) {
        if (e.target.files.length) {
            $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(e.target.files[0].name);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: If someone cancels out of the file upload, `e.target.files` will be empty and throw an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.  If you check the length of `e.target.files` you can avoid the console error.  Though functionally nothing is broken.

Comment: @phyatt no it does not. At least not in Edge, Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: for the second simpler snippet example.  The first example is fine.

Comment: @phyatt i tried to reproduce. But there are no errors when opening the file dialog and then pressing cancel...? What browser/os are you using?

Comment: Chrome on MacOS.  First I select a valid file and click okay to the file browser. Then I reopen the file dialog again and cancel out.  I should probably make a jsfiddle to show it off.

Comment: @phyatt, found it and fixed it. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Also make sure to add "overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" to the .custom-file-label otherwise lots of selected files will spill over down your page.

Answer (score 35):

```
$(document).on('change', '.custom-file-input', function (event) {
    $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(event.target.files[0].name);
})
```

Best of all worlds. Works on dynamically created inputs, and uses actual file name.

Answer (score 10):

This works with Bootstrap 4.1.3:

```
<script>
    $("input[type=file]").change(function () {
        var fieldVal = $(this).val();

        // Change the node's value by removing the fake path (Chrome)
        fieldVal = fieldVal.replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "");

        if (fieldVal != undefined || fieldVal != "") {
            $(this).next(".custom-file-label").attr('data-content', fieldVal);
            $(this).next(".custom-file-label").text(fieldVal);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Johann-S solution works great. (And it looks like he created the awesome plugin)

The Bootstrap 4.3 documentation example page uses this plugin to modify the filename: https://github.com/Johann-S/bs-custom-file-input

Use the [Bootstrap custom file input classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/#custom-file-input). Add the plugin to your project, and add this code in your script file on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  bsCustomFileInput.init()
})
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want you can use the recommended Bootstrap plugin to dynamize your custom file input: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bs-custom-file-input

This plugin can be use with or without jQuery and works with React an Angular

Comment: This works nicely: https://www.codeply.com/go/uGJOpHUd8L/file-input

Answer (score 3):

When you have multiple files, an idea is to show only the first file and the number of the hidden file names.

```
$('.custom-file input').change(function() {
    var $el = $(this),
    files = $el[0].files,
    label = files[0].name;
    if (files.length > 1) {
        label = label + " and " + String(files.length - 1) + " more files"
    }
    $el.next('.custom-file-label').html(label);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('#elementID').change(function(event){
        var fileName = event.target.files[0].name;
        if (event.target.nextElementSibling!=null){
            event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText=fileName;
        }
    });
</script>
```