# Translating custom-file input Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap and following this doc:

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLang" lang="es">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">Seleccionar Archivo</label>
</div>

$custom-file-text: (
  en: "Browse",
  es: "Elegir"
);
```

The input text isnt being translated even with `lang="es"` attribute added.

Here there is a codepen, what am I missing?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxGNrw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because Bootstrap SASS isn't imported into the Codepen. You first need to `@import "bootstrap/functions"` (since that's where $custom-file-text() lives), make the changes, and finally `@import "bootstrap"`....

```
@import "bootstrap/functions";

$custom-file-text: (
  en: "Browse",
  es: "Elegir"
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

I don't know of way to import the Bootstrap SASS into Codepen, but here's a working example on Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/2Mo9OrokBQ

---

Related question:
[Bootstrap 4 File Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250263/bootstrap-4-file-input/43255741#43255741)

Comment: are you sure you are not overwriting `$custom-file-text` when you import bootstrap?

Comment: @MarcosDiPaolo yes, because if you look in the bootstrap scss files you'll see it's using `!default`

Answer (score 9):

Well, the best way to achieve that is just to overide the CSS pseudo-class ::after

```
.custom-file-label::after { content: "Charger";}
```

Comment: Fast and dirty +1 :-)

Comment: .custom-file-input:lang(fr) .custom-file-label::after { content: "Parcourir"; }

Answer (score 0):

If overriding CSS, it's better to use the ":lang()" selector to apply your label only for a given language:

```
.custom-file-input:lang(fr) .custom-file-label::after {
    content: "Parcourir";
}
```