# Displaying uploaded file name in bootstrap 4 : custom-file class

Tags: bootstrap-4

Curious to know if the below mentioned will work. If not, why wouldn't it?

I assume two types of classes in my html for a file upload.

**Type 1**: `form-control` and

**Type 2**: `custom-file-input`.

On using the class `form-control`, I have my upload file name being shown, but on using `custom-file-input`, it doesn't.

Is there a way to display the uploaded file name in `custom-file-input` class?

Guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Comment: No Mena ! Not yet.

Comment: This helped help, look it up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250263/bootstrap-4-file-input

Comment: Thanks Mena. That helped  :)