# Handling the selection of a file from a file input

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I'm trying to have the filename of a chosen file appear in the body of a file picker. This is an Asp.Net Core view. I have the following file input:

```
<div class="form-group file-upload-wrapper">
    <input id="the-file" type="file" name="name" onchange="handleFile()" />    
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="the-file">Choose a file</label>                        
</div>
```

I want the filename to appear in place of the `Choose a file` text.

My JS looks like this:

```
@section Scripts {
<script language="javascript"> 

    function handleFile(file) {
        console.log(file);         
    }
```

As it currently stands, I'm getting an error:

```
ReferenceError: handleFile is not defined
```

My assumption is that `handleFile` needs to look something like this:

```
document.getElementById("the-file").title = file.files[0].name;
```

Am I on the right lines with this, and why am I getting the above error?

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/L2r7at39/)

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a fiddle? jsfiddle

Comment: Added the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use event handler for that. Remove `onchange` attribute form that element and use below:

```js
document.getElementById('the-file')
  .addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    handleFile(e)
  });

function handleFile(file) {
  console.log(file.target.value);
}
```

### Here is the snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('the-file')
  .addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    handleFile(e)
  });

function handleFile(file) {
  console.log(file.target.value);
  log(file.target.value);
}

function log(msg) {
 document.getElementById('result').innerText = msg;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group file-upload-wrapper">
  <input id="the-file" type="file" name="name" />
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="the-file">Choose a file</label>
</div>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#file-browser) , you need to modify the code like below:

```
<div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="the-file" name="name"/>
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="the-file">Choose a file</label>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
  <script>
     document.getElementById('the-file').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        var fileName = document.getElementById("the-file").files[0].name;
        var nextSibling = e.target.nextElementSibling
         nextSibling.innerText = fileName
     }); 
  </script>

}
```

You could refer to  [Bootstrap 4 File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43255741/10201850) Input for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> why am I getting the above error?

The code within the fiddle is different from the OP. I'll take the code on Fiddle as an example.

1. First of all, note that you added a `bootstrp.min.js` reference, however, you didn't add a jquery for it. Because `bootstrap.min.js` has a dependency on `jquery`, **it throws before the `handleFile()` function is defined.**

   That's why we could see an error of `util.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at util.js:56` in the console. To fix that issue, either **add a `jquery.min.js` before the `bootstrap.min.js`**:

   [image]

   Or change the loading behavior of your js like:

   [image]
2. And then you mix up the js statement with a function reference by :

   ```
   <input id="the-file" type="file" name="name" onchange="this.handleFile" />
   ```

   Note you should put a js statement instead of a single function reference within `onchange="..."`. That being said, you could fix it by:

   ```
   <input id="the-file" type="file" name="name" onchange="handleFile(event.target.files)" />
   ```
3. Your `handleFile()` uses a `this` that points to the `window` at runtime. As a result, it throws when invoked. Since we have passed the `files` as the arguments, change the function as below:

   ```
    function handleFile(files) {       
       console.log(files);         
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="form-group file-upload-wrapper">
  <script>
    const handleFile = file => {
      console.log(file);         
     } 
    </script>
    
    <input id="the-file" type="file" name="name" value ="file" onchange="handleFile(value)" />    
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="the-file">Choose a file</label>                        
</div>
```