# bootstrap 4 - upload file - change browse label

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a HTML form with Bootstrap 4 that uploads a file:

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFileLang" lang="it">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFileLang">Seleziona un file</label>
</div>
```

How can I change the "browse" label with "seleziona"?

Thanks

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250263/bootstrap-4-file-input) out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 File Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250263/bootstrap-4-file-input)