# How to change "Choose file" text using Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, file-upload, bootstrap-5

Is it impossible change choose file text of input file in Bootstrap 5 using CSS like Bootstrap 4?

And how can I add a margin to "No file chosen"?

[image]

Comment: Same question for [Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43250263/)

Comment: Have a try on this, some tricks are used but just works fine.  
 [stackoverflow.com/a/73138618/8706905](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73138618/8706905)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 beta no longer provides a [custom file input like Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250263/bootstrap-4-file-input/43255741#43255741) that used pseudo elements to override the [browser's file input defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001586/change-the-no-file-chosen/16001704). Therefore you'd have to use JS or make your own psuedo element to hide the `Choose file`.. area of the input...

```css
#formFile::before {
  content: "Pick file";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container min-vh-100 py-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works fine on Chrome but not on Firefox!

Comment: There's a bit of text showing behind the button mask. It should probably have a flexible width. Also, it shows the wrong color when clicked.

Comment: Weird, maybe because my original answer was BS 5 beta

Comment: We are now at 5.2. Any thoughts on newest approach?

Answer (score 22):

## Bootstrap 5 + some CSS

1. Compose Bootstrap's [custom file input](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/input-group/#custom-file-input) with custom label.
2. Hide default `Choose file` button with the [`::file-selector-button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button) pseudo-element. There are pseudo-elements `::-webkit-file-upload-button` and `::-ms-browse` for older versions of Chrome/Opera/Safari and Edge/IE respectively. But [bootstrap.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.css) uses `::file-selector-button` and `::-webkit-file-upload-button` only. So I propose to do the same.
3. Add some more CSS for the `:hover` effect and for the thin border between the label and the input field.

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/VwMQWGE

```css
.custom-file-button input[type=file] {
  margin-left: -2px !important;
}

.custom-file-button input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  display: none;
}

.custom-file-button input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
  display: none;
}

.custom-file-button:hover label {
  background-color: #dde0e3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container py-3">

  <div class="input-group custom-file-button">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile">Your Custom Text</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="inputGroupFile">
  </div>

</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 3):

If the file input is placed inside the label element and then hidden the label itself will act as the file input when it is clicked. Adding the `form-control` class and the tabindex attribute (which specifies that the element can be focused) to the label will then style it like a generic Bootstrap input.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-text">Custom Add-on Text</span>
  <label class="form-control" tabindex="0">Custom Input Text
    <input type="file" class="invisible">
  </label>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/yetiface/pen/PoQqrda

This solution has its downsides, for example the label element will not automatically receive bootstrap styles specifically for `input[type='file']`. However it is such a simple method that I felt it worth posting for those who it can help.

Comment: Also, it doesn't show the filename when selected

Answer (score 2):

I needed to change both texts so this method helped

```js
$('#review-image').change(function(e) {
    let fileName = (e.target.files.length > 0) ? e.target.files[0].name : 'choose_file_not';
    $('#review-image-label').text(fileName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="input-group custom-file-button">
    <label class="input-group-text" for="review-image" role="button">choose_file</label>
    <label for="review-image" class="form-control" id="review-image-label" role="button">choose_file_not</label>
    <input type="file" class="d-none" id="review-image" name="images[]" multiple accept="image/*">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an input group with a label, the input, and then appended another label. This way you can style it however you want and put custom text as the input group text. You then hide the input element (display:none or width:0 or something)

Examples:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>Label before</p>

<div class='input-group'>
  <label class='input-group-prepend'>
    <div class='input-group-text form-control' for='file-input-thing'>Pick File</div>
  </div>
  <input type='file' id='file-input-thing' style='width:0;'>
  <label id='file-input-label' class='form-control' for='file-input-thing'/>
</div>

<p>Label after</p>

<div class='input-group'>
  <label id='file-input-label' class='form-control' for='file-input-thing'/>
  <input type='file' id='file-input-thing' style='width:0;'>
  <div class='input-group-append'>
    <label class='input-group-text form-control' for='file-input-thing'>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then assign styling to labels as you see fit. By making both piece labels tied into the input element it allows you to click on either and choose a file.
Further you can add an ID to the blank label and update the value to the name of the file.

```
let inputElement = document.getElementById('file-input-thing');
let inputLabel= document.getElementById('file-input-label');

inputElement.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let file = e.target.files[0];
  inputLabel.innerHTML = file.name;
})
```

I'm new to all this so there's probably a better solution, but this worked for me.

Comment: I converted your markup to a snippet. Looks like it needs some polish. There are extra closing div tags, and you wouldn't want two labels for an input.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have implemented it,
just copy-paste it to your code and you'll see the results

```
<Button onClick={() => document.getElementById('imageFileSelect').click()}>Choose Image</Button>
<input className="form-control d-none"  id='imageFileSelect' type="file" onChange={imageSelected}></input>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the file input field to dark moode and added: data-bs-theme="dark"

```
<div class="mb-3" data-bs-theme="gray">
        <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Default file input example</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile"></div>
```